# training image datasets for object detection

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, yolo

Which version of YOLO-tensorflow (customised cnn like googlenet) is preferred for traffic science?

If the training datasets are blurred and are with noise is that okay to train or what are the steps to be considered for training dataset images?

Comment: I am working on seatbelt detection at cross roads and for that i need images but which are not soo good so please cananyone tell me what to do ?

Comment: Get a degree in statistics and machine learning! Just to clarify. I'm not attempting to be rude! What I'm insinuating is that if you don't know what you're doing, this is really hard to achieve. A place to start is [Ian Goodfellow's free online book on deep learning](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/).

Comment: thank you  Andreas Storvik Strauman but I dont have enough time can you please tell me any other way

Comment: I would start by seeing how convnets (CNNs) perform (e.g. try FCN8 for segmentic classification). Maybe look at some denoising autoencoder (if you have sufficient data to train it on).

Comment: You could ask over at [ai.se]

Comment: thank you Andreas Storvik Strauman yeah I will check .

Answer (score 0):

You may need to curate your own dataset using frames from a traffic camera and manually tagging images with cars where the passengers' seatbelts are or are not buckled, as this is a very specialized task. From there, you can do data augmentation (perhaps using the Keras ImageDataGenerator class). If a human can identify a seatbelt in an image that is blurred or noisy, a model can learn from it. From there, you can use transfer learning from a pre-trained CNN model like Inception ([this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfNvhPx5Px8) is a helpful tutorial for how to do that), or train your own binary classifier with your tagged images, where your inputs are frames of traffic camera video.

I'd suggest that after learning the basics of CNNs with these models, only then should you dive into a more complicated model like yolo.

Comment: thankyou Josh Payne bro I am still collecting images for training datasets and i planned to use minimum of 5000 images in each dataset that is with and without seatbelts. Do I need to do any preprocessing to my dataset images?

Comment: but Josh Payne bro I dont want to do transfer learning I want to train my code from the start coz I have a GPU 1050.

Comment: For preprocessing, you can do data augmentation (I mentioned [Keras](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)). You'll likely need a very large dataset if you expect good performance when training from scratch. Those big models out there trained on ImageNet took several weeks to train on multiple GPUs so it may be to your advantage to make use of their weights. Check out [this link](http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/) for more clarity to why transfer learning can be helpful and where to use it.

Comment: josh Payne bro I have a doubt I am using 4000 images per each class i mean 4000 for with seat class and 4000 for without seatbelts. Is that data enough? and I have heard that data augmentation is for increasing the number of images for traing data right? so how can I do preprocessing with that? my images are noisy as they are from real time and so what shall I do is that okay to train with that same noisy images or shall do some thing ?

Comment: I am going to use YOLO v3 bro and in this I will use Inception CNN